# profile_update hook does not fire from front-end

Tags: hooks, actions, profiles, events

I'm using BuddyPress to allow users to log in on the Front end. Once logged in, they can click on 'My Account'. On this page they can upload avatars, edit their account information, etc.

When I upload a new avatar from this page, the 'profile_update' hook does not fire.

If I remain logged in as the same user and navigate to the backend (/wp-admin) and upload a new avatar from there, the 'profile_update' hook fires successfully.

Why would the hook only fire when accessed from /wp-admin and not the website front end ?

Comment: Because that’s what the hook is for? WordPress doesn’t have a front end profile form, so if a plugin has added one then it needs to use its own hook or fire this one. You’ll need to check with the plugin author or read its documentation to figure out your options. 3rd party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: Ok - I figured that any change to the WordPress user profile, be it front end or back, would cause the profile_update hook to fire, but seemingly you are correct in that it is limited to the backend.